Using PutAppend to create data file for 2D plot
I need to append 2 real numbers x,y (a point coordinates) to the bottom of a file, so that these numbers form 2 columns, the x column and the y column. I need to plot the points later. Doing this:
PutAppend[x,y,file]

appends the number y below the number x, i.e. I get a single column. Doing this:
PutAppend[{x,y},file]

creates what looks like 2 columns, but the curly brackets are there, and I don't need them. Doing this:
PList = {{x,y}};
PutAppend[Flatten[PList[[1]]], file]

also keeps the curly brackets, etc.

Create a string and append it to the file.

Since you mentioned you are going to plot the points later, why not keep the curly brackets? {x, y} >>> "test.txt"; ListPlot[ReadList["test.txt"]]

@DanielHuber, note that using string will also produce double quotes ("") in the file.

@Domen E.g. WriteString does not include quotes.

@DanielHuber, sure, but this is not using PutAppend then ... I suggest you make answer using your idea as an alternative :)

There are various ways to achieve this. You can, for example, use the OutputForm of a Row, which simply puts the elements one after another. You then have to manually add the comma (or whichever delimiter you want):
PutAppend[OutputForm[Row[{x, ",", y}]], file]

If you need this often, create an auxiliary function:
row[data_] := OutputForm[Row[Riffle[data, ","]]]

PutAppend[row[{x, y, z, w, u, r}], file]


Thanks Domen ! Works just fine.

As an alternative you may use "WriteString". The following writes a text file:
s1 = "test\n";
file = "d:/Tmp/test.txt";
WriteString[file, s1];
WriteString[file, s1];
Close[file]

The file contains then:
test
test

